# How to configure Multiple Sites using Ubuntu + Apache with the same IP on different physical servers?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have two Moodle sites. An old one and a new one.
Each of them on Ubuntu Server with Apache on different physical servers. Is it possible to make them work using the same ip and domain name with different ports?
How should I configure apache and its Virtual Host?

Example>
[www.example.com/moodle1](http://www.example.com/moodle1) << 111.111.11.11:80 and
[www.example.com/moodle2](http://www.example.com/moodle2) << 11.111.11.11:8081

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to put a reverse proxy or load balancer like haproxy in front and have your two physical servers as backend servers.

You describe one of the servers as "old"; if you're planning to decommission that server eventually then you could set the web server on the "new" server to proxy to the "old" server for only the legacy sites that are on the "old" server.

Either way you are having one piece of software on one server listen on one IP:port combination and fetch the answers for some or all requests from a backend server or servers that would be on a different IP.

You can't have two hosts in the same routed network have the same IP at the same time. You can split it up into several networks using ECMP or by BGP advertising host routes but this is an advanced topic and if it's not something you've ever heard of then you're probably not in a position to do it.

It might also be worth examining why you think you need both hosts to have the same IP, as there might be a more obvious way to achieve whatever it is you're actually trying to do.